# Rails 6 before save callback not fired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, rails-activerecord

I am trying to assign a random number to an attribute named `position` before my `Product` objects are saved. I cannot get the callback to work properly. There are no errors in the console, it just silently fails.

Here is my model

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
validates_presence_of :position
before_save {
    assign_position
}

private
    def assign_position
        self.position = rand(150)
    end
end
```

This is my schema

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "position"
end
```

Here is an example seed I'm using to test the before save callback.

```
Product.create(name: "Rose Deep Hydration Facial Toner")
```

There are no errors but the console output when I check after creating the seed

```
irb(main):079:0> Product.find_by_name("Rose Deep Hydration Facial Toner").position
Product Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."name" = $1 ORDER BY "products"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $2  [["name", "Rose Deep Hydration Facial Toner"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> nil
```

I have other callbacks in the application that work just fine. I can't figure out why this one is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that validations happen before `before_save` callbacks are triggered. You have this:

```
validates_presence_of :position
```

but `position` will still be `nil` when that validation is checked.

I think you want to use a `before_validation` callback instead of `before_save`:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :assign_position
  validates_presence_of :position

private

  def assign_position
    self.position = rand(150)
  end
end
```

Keep in mind that `assign_position` will get called every time you validate a Product so updating a typo in the name (for example) will change the `position`. You might want to leave the position alone if it is already set or if you're altering an existing instance.